# Cómo instalar una Oracle Client Library con Python desde un Notebook de Jupyter

Tags: python, linux, oracle, jupyter

Estoy tratando de establecer una conexiòn desde un Notebook de Jupyter usando el siguiente código de Python:

```
!pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
import cx_Oracle
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("<myhost>", 1521, service_name="<myservice>")
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("<myuser>", "<mypassword>", dsn, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Y obtengo este mensaje de error:

---

> DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn("", 1521, service_name="")
>   ----> 2 connection = cx_Oracle.connect("", "", dsn, encoding="UTF-8")
>
> DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library:
>   "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory". See
>   https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help

---

En el link no hay información específica de cómo instalar la librería en Linux usando Python.

Cómo puedo hacer esta instalación?

Comment: Podrías traducir tu pregunta ya que el sitio es para preguntas en español.

Comment: Hola, no se si ya instalaste el cliente de Oracle en tu máquina que es el que usa la librería que quieres usar. Ya que ocupa `libclntsh.so`